# Make WebService just return plain text JSON?

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, web-services

I am trying to use web services to return a json list of resources that FullCallendar Resource is requesting:

Here is the web service class:

```
/// <summary>
/// Summary description for CalendarServices
/// </summary>
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
// To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
// [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
public class CalendarServices : System.Web.Services.WebService
{
    public CalendarServices()
    {
    }

    [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public string GetEmployees()
    {

        List<object> eventList = new List<object>();
        var emps = ResourceManager.GetAllEmployees();
        foreach (Employee e in emps)
        {
            eventList.Add(
           new
           {
               id = e.EmployeID.ToString(),
               name = e.EmployeName
           }
       );

        }



        JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        string strJSON = js.Serialize(eventList);
        return strJSON;
    }
}
```

Here is where it is called:

```
var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    header: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: ''
    },
    defaultView: 'resourceNextWeeks',
    numberOfWeeks: 5,
    weekends: false,
    editable: true,
    selectable: true,
    minTime: 8,
    maxTime: 16,
    refetchResources: true,
    selectHelper: true,
    resources: 'CalendarServices.asmx/GetEmployees'
        ,
    events: [
        {
```

I am not sure why this is not working. Maybe I do not understand web services?

In the example, they call resources.php which just echos it.

Essentially that I would like is if I go to CalendarServices.asmx/GetEmployees

I want to see this in my browser:

```
[
{
"name":"Resource 2",
"id":"resource2"
},
{
"name":"Resource 1",
"id":"resource1"}
]
```

Just plain text will do. Currently if I try this url in my browser it crashes.

What can I do?

Thanks

The crash:

```
Request format is unrecognized for URL unexpectedly ending in '/GetEmployees'.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: Request format is unrecognized for URL unexpectedly ending in '/GetEmployees'.

Source Error: 

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace: 


[InvalidOperationException: Request format is unrecognized for URL unexpectedly ending in '/GetEmployees'.]
   System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebServiceHandlerFactory.CoreGetHandler(Type type, HttpContext context, HttpRequest request, HttpResponse response) +489333
   System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebServiceHandlerFactory.GetHandler(HttpContext context, String verb, String url, String filePath) +212
   System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory.GetHandler(HttpContext context, String requestType, String url, String pathTranslated) +47
   System.Web.HttpApplication.MapHttpHandler(HttpContext context, String requestType, VirtualPath path, String pathTranslated, Boolean useAppConfig) +226
   System.Web.MapHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +145
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155
```

Comment: Is that crash accompanied by a line number and perhaps an error message that might hint at what the problem is?

Comment: ASMX is a legacy technology, and should not be used for new development. WCF should be used for all new development of web service clients and servers. One hint: Microsoft has retired the [ASMX Forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/asmxandxml/threads) on MSDN.

Comment: Did you try uncommenting the line for which it says it should be uncommented to use it in AJAX calls?

Answer (score 0):

Can you check in fiddler to see if your request type is POST or GET, you may have to stick an extra bit in your code. ie

```
[WebInvoke(Method="POST",ResponseFormat=WebMessageFormat.Json)]
```